# Usage of "as" for comparison

Tags: word-usage, comparisons

Can we use "**as**" in this manner?

**It is very hot here in the summers. However it isn't as hot in the countryside.**

or

**It is very hot here in the summers. However in the countryside, it isn't as hot.**

I've searched the web but only found sources using ***as...as*** for comparison. I think my sentences just convey the same meaning as

**It is very hot here in the summers. However it isn't as hot in the countryside** [*as it is here*]

where "*as it is here*" is implied.

## edit

If I simply say "*It isn't as hot in the countryside.*" without any context will it be fine?

I'm worried because I found some examples [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/just-as-good-bad-big-etc) where they're using the phrase without context.

**Is the structure I'm trying to form not popular enough because all I can find on the web is *as...as* comparison?**

**Is it always necessary that '*as*' has to be followed by '*as*' while making comparisons**?

Comment: Yes, either is fine.

Comment: "Hot in the countryside" is a comparative clause that is obligatorily reduced. In full we have "However, it isn't as hot in the countryside as it is hot here in the summer".

Comment: It means that some phrase must be dropped in order to make the sentence acceptable. We can't say "However, it isn't as hot in the countryside as it is hot here in the summer". That makes no sense, so we must drop the phrase "as it is hot here in the summer".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fine. The part in square brackets ([as it is in the city]) is only needed if you don't give the other person full context. However, in the course of a dialogue, you've likely already provided all the info they need so

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you're looking for the classic construction, your phrase will look like this:

"It isn't as hot in the countryside as it is here in summers" (The "It is very hot here" is implied)

Comment: I'd say it was "it isn't as hot in the countryside as it is hot here in the summer".